# how to run 64bit jdk on solaris10 64bit

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, jvm-arguments, solaris-10

I am running solaris10 SPARC 64-bit on my dev box, I am trying to install jdk6 64 bit. according to oracle official document, I need install 32 bit jdk6 for it first and then install 64 bit jdk6 which is like a patch containing extra software for 64bit.

On SPARC processors:  Install solaris-sparc (32-bit) with solaris-sparcv9 (64-bit)

1. install jdk6 32 bit ./jdk-6  -solaris-sparcv9.sh
2. install jdk6 64 bit ./jdk-6  -solaris-x64.sh

after intallation, when I run java -version, it still show this is 32 bit jvm.

I am wondering how to use 64 bit jvm, I have to add jvm option like -d64 to enable 64 bit in my launch stripts?

also what is the benefit of 64 bit jvm?

if I do not use jvm 64 bit optioin in my script, do I need install 64 bit patch at all?

what is the difference between 32 bit and 64 bit form application developer's perspective?

Answer (score 1):

The 32bit and the 46bit versioins get installed at different places. You either have the 32bit version in front of the 64bit version in your PATH variable or the 64bit Version is not in the PATH at all.

You can set the PATH variable in one of the startup scripts like .Profile, or at the beginning of your shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the `-d64` flag as  you note, is generally enough to select the 64-bit JVM:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

vs.

```
$ java -d64 -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

There's not much difference from a development perspective. The benefits would mostly revolve around larger amount of addressable memory and manipulation of large numbers. It would depend on your usage but there's no compelling reason to use the 64-bit JVM in this scenario if you don't have these requirements.